# How to display a table (rows and columns of data) in an iPhone native app?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I want to display a table like the following in an iPhone app

```
Recommendations History

              Current   1 Month Ago   2 Months Ago  3 Months Ago
Strong Buy  29              27          27            26 
Moderate Buy    5            4          4              4 
Hold            3               4          3              3 
Moderate Sell   0            0          0              0 
Strong Sell     0               1          1              0 
Mean Rec.   1.29           1.44         1.39          1.29
```

I am trying to figure how to render this chart in a native iPhone app in a way that is easy for the user to scan through.

The UITableView seems to be of no help for displaying tables like this. 
This is actually not the only table that I have to display to the user and the number of columns and types can vary.
The table display that I am looking for should let the user easily scan through larger tables (though not very large at this point) by may be zooming in and out.

Actually I am not even sure if such data should be shown as a regular table in the iPhone UI. Are there any better approaches to displaying such data from a user's perspective?

Are there iPhone UI components which handle this?

Comment: Would displaying the data as HTML be a bad idea for your app? You can use UIWebView for that.

Comment: I was thinking it might be an overkill, but will explore this option as well. It will surely work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done with a table view, you just need to write custom view cell code to give the illusion of columns in the table

[here is a blog posting](http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html)